# Why do teenagers produce their melatonin later than everyone else

Tags: sleep, sleep-cycles

Does anybody have a theory why this change happens to teenagers? Everything I have read agrees it does happen, but nobody seems to suggest a reason why this has evolved.

> Biology’s cruel joke goes something like this: As a teenage body goes
>   through puberty, its circadian rhythm essentially shifts three hours
>   backward. Suddenly, going to bed at nine or ten o’clock at night isn’t
>   just a drag, but close to a biological impossibility. Studies of
>   teenagers around the globe have found that adolescent brains do not
>   start releasing melatonin until around eleven o’clock at night and
>   keep pumping out the hormone well past sunrise.

https://www.brainpickings.org/2013/07/17/sleep-and-the-teenage-brain/